# How to run linux command before starting up git bash terminal

Tags: linux, bash, docker, git-bash

I am working with Docker on my windows machine via git bash. Since git bash does not record the current status on closing, I need to set some environment variables related to Docker every time when I start a new terminal. The command I would like to run before start-up is:

```
eval $(docker-machine env)
```

Or better yet, have a bash script including other logics. For example if docker machine is not up, start the machine first, etc. Is there a way to automatically run bash command or script before opening a new git bash window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend creating a new file under your home folder(`~/`) namely `~/.bashrc` which is read by your terminal when it first starts-up. Add a function say `myStartUpFunction()` that runs your command as you need.

```
myStartUpFunction() {
    docker-machine env
}

myStartUpFunction
```

This would enable you to run the `docker-machine env` every time a new terminal session is opened.

Comment: Is it possible to call a python script from .bashrc? The stuff I need to run might be a little complex which involves parsing output of one command and run another. I am more comfortable using Python in that sense.

Comment: @ddd: You can call any python script within the function, as long as you call with the full absolute path.